# What is the function of this device? What kit? Black remote with 5 buttons and 3 AAA batteries?

Tags: piece-information, remote-control

[image]
Some kind of IR device #s on cover 41305 #s on outside case 4252

[image]
LEDs appear to be IR transmitter and receiver. Red and white
LEDs also seen.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [Spybotics remote from 2002](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4232rc#T=C).

[image: front] [image: back]

It came in [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4232rc&in=S), and works with the receiver in those sets. I found [this page which talks a bit about them](https://pbrick.info/spybotics-faqs/).